# db4o: set and get method not available?

Tags: java, db4o

```
ObjectContainer db=Db4o.openFile(Util.DB4OFILENAME);
db.get(); //doesn't exist
```

eclipse shows openFile is deprecitated with strike out.

I don't have get or set method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .get / .set method have been deprecated for a long time and been replaced by .store() and .query().

You're example should be like this, when using a query:

```
ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Util.DB4OFILENAME);
db.query(new Predicate<MyClass>(){
      public boolean match(MyClass c){
            return c.getName().equals("Joe"); 
      }
})
```

What version of the [tutorial are](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/tutorial/) you using? Because it shouldn't have any get/set references in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found this http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/resources/dRS-6.0-tutorial-java.pdf
and looking at their use of DB4o.openFile(filename) it doesn't look like any get method is needed. I'm not experienced just did some looking up.